# How to keep the middle part from a text string using gsub / sub?

Tags: r, regex

This is what i came up with, but it doesn't work perfectly (it's more likely that some of the results are correct by accident):

```
dd <- c ("2day-2023-1-5--20-0.csv", "1day-2023-2-5--20-0.csv", "3day-2021-1-5--20-0.csv")
sub("day-.(.*)--.*", "\\1", dd)
```

Expected output would be

```
"2023-1-5" "2023-2-5" "2021-1-5"
```

Comment: try `sub(^\\dday-(.*)--.*', '\\1', dd)`

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question because if the dot is seen as a typo, it will still not solve the issue and the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a dot in your pattern here `day-.(.*)--.*` that matches any character.

In this case it matches the first digit of the year, so that will not be in group 1, and you don't match the leading digit before "day" and that will result in a wrong result like "1023-2-5"

You could match optional digits before `day` and then match as least as possible characters before matching the  `--`

```
\d*day-(.*?)--.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jl4bw0/1)

Or make the pattern more specific and match 1 or more leading digits:

```
\d+day-(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})--.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pobGiz/1)

For example

```
dd <- c ("2day-2023-1-5--20-0.csv", "1day-2023-2-5--20-0.csv", "3day-2021-1-5--20-0.csv")
sub("\\d+day-(\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2})--.*", "\\1", dd)
```

Result

```
[1] "2023-1-5" "2023-2-5" "2021-1-5"
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem and even more for the tips you provided

Answer (score 2):

A complete different, probably helpful, approach:

Here we directly extract the date part from each string in `dd` and convert it into a Date object.

```
library(parsedate)
library(lubridate)

as_date(parse_date(dd))
```

```
[1] "2023-01-05" "2023-02-05" "2021-01-05"
```